# how to dump entire neo4j database

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Hi guys how to dump entire database i'm using neo4j shell tolls to export entire data he is my query "export-cypher -r -b 10 -o /dump.cypher MATCH (n)<-[r]->(p)  return n,r,p
" but few relations are not creating.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at the APOC Procedures plugin for Neo4j. It has [export procedures](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures#export--import) which should accomplish exactly what you need.